# How to append key-value in dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try do this:

```
myjson['card'].update(key: value)
```

But instead of this:

```
{'hey_this_is_key1': 'My angry value'}
```

I get this:

```
{'key': 'My angry value'}
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: what is `key`? what is `value`? please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: my function have variables key and value. key = 'some text', value='some value'. But in result I get {'key': 'some value'}. In this case it's just variables.

Comment: kindly add the sample JSON & whats the value of key/value pair ?

Comment: Are you sure have not written `myjson['card'].update('key': value)`? We need more information to help you.

Comment: the code you posted here will not produce the output you posted here. this is not reproducible.

Comment: myjson['card'].update(keyz= valuez)  - WORKS ! But in keyz variable I have some 'BLA BLA BLA'. But in my json I see this: "keyz": ["Sometext"], But I want to see 'BLA BLA BLA': 'Sometext'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dict syntax `{}` in the `update` method.

**Ex:**

```
card = {}
key = "Hello"
value = "World"
card.update({key:value})
print(card)
```

**Output:**

```
{'Hello': 'World'}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works perfect! I was know that problem is simple. I just don't know perfect how update method works. Thanks again.

Comment: Or even better: `card[key] = value`